# How to install jenkins under current user (not 'jenkins') on MAC OS X

Tags: macos, jenkins

I have configured MAC OS X environment (SDKs, licenses, etc) under current user for build server and would like to reuse all the settings by a build agent. Jenkins was chosen as a good option but for some reason during installation it created a new user **jenkins** and launch the app under it, causing the environment setup to be not accessible (no SDKs, no licenses are found anymore).

Is it possible to install jenkins under current user?
Probably it could be installed under jenkins but then launched under current user?

Any other good options for me to consider are appreciated.

Comment: How was it installed? From the native Mac .pkg? The .war from their website? Is it running an embedded web server, or on Tomcat?

Comment: I'm free to choose the installation approach. Environment is setup under USER1 (for example) and I want install and run jenkins under the same USER1 to share all the SDKs, licenses and other setup I did. Before I tried to install it from native package installer - it setups separate user, then I tried "jenkins app" which used to work fine but now it wouldn't start (timeout), now I'm looking for .war install with custom container but it is hard task for me. I'm looking for straightforward solution to setup jenkins under the USER1 account.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this: http://www.sailmaker.co.uk/blog/2013/04/02/advanced-jenkins-for-ios-and-mac/#Installing-Jenkins-itself

> I’m also going to recommend installing Jenkins via Homebrew, to avoid
>   some nonsense in Jenkins’ own installer whereby it puts itself in
>   /Users/Shared/. You really don’t want that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're free to reinstall however you'd like, I'd recommend re-installing as the user you want to use, using whatever type of install you prefer, and then simply copy over the old *Jenkins* data directory to the new installation's location, and then changing the permissions in that directory.

That is to say, the directory containing the config, plugin and job information (it may be something like `/usr/lib/jenkins`, but could vary).

Then, `chown -R` the data directory using the user:group info you want to use so *Jenkins* has access to the files.

I have used this type of method in the past to transfer all the data from one install to another totally separate install on the same box, and it has worked well (one could use this method to transfer the data to an install on another box, as well).

**Note:** I would highly recommend making a full backup of the data directory before doing this, in case anything goes awry.

Comment: This worked for me: `sudo chown -R jenkins /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs` I had to do that because I copied the jobs from a different machine