# Xcodebuild code signing error on Jenkins

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, code-signing, xcodebuild

I get the following code signing error when trying to build my app using xcodebuild on jenkins

```
Code Sign error: No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the team ID “xxxxxxxxxx” were found.
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Framework' in SDK 'iOS 8.3'
```

I am able to build it from the xcode GUI however with no problem.  What is going on here? Clearly the computer has everything it needs to build an .ipa file but I can't do that through Jenkins and xcodebuild

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins by default runs as "`jenkins`" user. Clearly the signing identities and mobile provisioning profiles are stored per user profile in `~`.

Either make your Jenkins run with the same user as your home user, or provide access to `jenkins` user to all your keychains and provisioning directories.

**Edit:**
Some answers on how to change user:   [How to install jenkins under current user (not 'jenkins') on MAC OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538366/how-to-install-jenkins-under-current-user-not-jenkins-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: thanks, how do I "make Jenkins run with the same user as my home user?" that would be great

Comment: How do you launch Jenkins?

Comment: There are some answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538366/how-to-install-jenkins-under-current-user-not-jenkins-on-mac-os-x

Comment: I launch it through the command line with the following command "java -jar /Applications/Jenkins/jenkins.war" I will check out your suggested stack overflow thread and see if I can use those answers too, thanks!